# Retrieve real-time technical indicators and data from a stock API for 500 stocks at once for free

Tags: api, stock, quandl, alpha-vantage, technical-indicator

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve values of highly-used technical indicators such as EMA, Simple Moving Average (SMA), Williams%R for a few hundred stocks that updates hourly for free over multiple API calls per minute.

The current solutions in the market are AlphaVantage's API which provides real-time data but limits you to 5 API calls per minute (which means you can get 1 technical indicator on 5 stocks maximum).

Other APIs such as Quandl and IEX, has much higher rates for API calls but the quotes data are offered per day (open/high/close/low).

Is there anything out in the market that allows me to do this for free? The purpose of using this data is to provide real-time (or at least close to 3/4-hourly) alerts if for example, the EMA-26 and EMA-12 intersects each other for any of a list of, say, 500 stocks, every few hours.

Comment: This is a primary reason I created an [open-source indicator library](https://daveskender.github.io/Stock.Indicators/) for indicators.  I figured it's easier to get free raw quote history and then compute on my own en-masse instead of burning through API limits; it's also way faster to compute than calling an API.  I'm working on a [Python wrapper](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators/issues/394) that might be of interest, soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many different APIs, I think the yfinance API is the best for batch downloads as you can simply use a list of stock symbols to fetch data. However, note that if you fetch data for multiple stocks that the pandas format changes to multilevel index array.